# ESRI javascript featureLayer.graphics

Tags: arcgis, esri

I'm working on a map that uses FeatureLayer.Mode_ONDEMAND. To see certain layer, I pass in a project ID using featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression. Where such layer exists, I see it. What I want to know is how to detect when no layer exists. I want to print an alert to the viewer instead of showing just a blank map. Here's my code:

```
function init() {
  map = new esri.Map("mapDiv", {
   basemap: "topo",
   zoom: 9
  });

  var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://services.arcgis.com/v01g34asdwfAi/arcgis/rest/services/Projects/FeatureServer/0",{
   mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
   outFields: ["*"],
   opacity: 1
  });


  featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("SrvyDescID=\'' . htmlspecialchars($ProjectID) . '\'");
  console.log(featureLayer.graphics);
  console.log(featureLayer.graphics[0]);
  map.addLayer(featureLayer);
   }
```

What I learned is when the project is valid, feature.graphics will return an array. But I'm unable to treat it like an array. For example:

console.log(featureLayer.graphics) returns an array object
but
console.log(featureLayer.graphics[0]) returns "undefined".

featureLayer.graphic.length also doesn't work. How do I use this array object to let me know that a layer is displayed on the map?

Attached is a screenshot of the console log. Thanks for your help.

[image: Console.log]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to catch "update-end" event. Final code:

```
map = new esri.Map("mapDiv", {
    center: [-118.30, 34.3],
    zoom: 8,
    basemap: "topo"
});



on(map, "update-end", function(){           // update-end event will execute after the layer has been added to the map
   if(featureLayer.graphics.length >= 1)
   {
       // do your thing         
   }
})   



var featureLayer = new     

    esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://services.arcgis.com/v01gqwMseaqNAi/arcgis/rest/services/Project_boundaries_021616/FeatureServer/0",{
   mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
   outFields: ["*"],
   opacity: 1                       
}); 

featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("SrvyDescID=\'' . htmlspecialchars($SDID) . '\'");                 
map.addLayer(featureLayer);
```